# How to call a javascript function after the selection of file from the Open Dialog window close event. in HTMLusing html file type="file"

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>
    <script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById('myfileId').onchange = function(e) { alert('change'); }
    </script>

    <form action="" >
        <input type="file"  id="myfileId" name="myfile">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

How can I call the JavaScript function after a file selection.

**Edit: 1**

```
<html>
<body>

    <form>
        <input type="file"  id="myfileId" name="myfile">
    </form>
 <script language="javascript">
  window.onload = function() 
        { 
    alert("Test");

    document.getElementById('myfileId').onblur =  function(e) { alert('change'); }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why there is no `<html>` element! In fact, I don't even know what language this is. </sarcasm> Could you add a bit of context to your question such as what error message and behavior(expected and actual) and such?

Comment: For your edit, I didn't actually mean to make a full HTML document. I just meant you needed more context such as "what error message and behavior(expected and actual)"

Comment: @Earlz I need to call a javascript function after the selection of file from the Open Dialog window close event.

Answer (score 8):

You have to put that `<script>` *after* the `<input>`. The `document.getElementById('myfileId')` does not exist if you put it before, so it will return nothing.

Comment: @coderex: Not reproducible. Hint: You need to close (confirm) the file choosing dialog to see the alert.

Comment: Change events tend to fire when focus is lost, not as soon as a change is made.

Comment: @KennyTM the onchange  is not wrking any morreee

Comment: @KennyTM check my edit section I added my latest code. you can check and let me know whats wrong

Comment: @coderex: Still works. Note that with `onblur` you need to click outside of the `<input>` to fire.

Comment: @KennyTM how can i trigger a JavaScript function, after file selection. ? Any option for that. ?

Answer (score 3):

As @Kenny says, you have to either put the script after the input declaration so the element actually exists when the script is executed, or alternatively, add the function to the document's `onload` event:

```
window.onload = function() 
        { document.getElementById('myfileId').onchange =  
          function(e) { alert('change'); }
        }
```